# Fix JQuery Countdown Timer in Rails 3 Application

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I need a countdown timer for a rails application I'm working on so I decided to use this.

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

In the public/javascripts folder I've added jquery.countdown.js
In the public/styleheets folder I've added jquery.countdown.css

In app/views/layouts/application.html.erb I add the javascript and css files to the stylesheet and javascript tags.

In my view I've added

```
<script>
    var element = '#countDownTimer';
    var year = <%= @deal.end.year %>;
    var month = <%= @deal.end.month %>;
    var day = <%= @deal.end.day %>;
   setCountdownTimer(element, year, month, day);
</script>
<div id="countDownTimer"></div>
```

which is going to be used to select with jQuery to add the timer.

Here is my application.js file

```
// The following function is called once the rest of the document is fully loaded
 $(document).ready(function()
 {  

function setCountdownTimer(element, year, month, day) {
  var date = new Date(year, month, day);
  $(element).countdown({until: date});
}


// DEALS TABS ON DEALS PAGES
$("#tabs > ul").tabs(); // Make the tabs.

// FANCYBOX FOR GALLERY IMAGES POPUP
$("a.galleryitem").fancybox();

// MEDIA ENCODER FOR PODCASTS
$.mb_audioEmbedder.playerPath="/media/player.swf" //the path to audio player
    $.mb_videoEmbedder.defaults.width=500;
$.mb_audioEmbedder.defaults.width=214;
    $("#media").mb_embedMovies();
    $("#media").mb_embedAudio();

});
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping

```
   var element = '#countDownTimer';
   var year = <%= @deal.end.year %>;
   var month = <%= @deal.end.month %>;
   var day = <%= @deal.end.day %>;
   setCountdownTimer(element, year, month, day);
```

inside a `$(document).ready()`

also I don't think this needs to be in the `$(document).ready()`

```
function setCountdownTimer(element, year, month, day) {
  var date = new Date(year, month, day);
  $(element).countdown({until: date});
}
```

The issue is probably that your calling setCountdownTimer before its defined

Comment: I tried that but still couldn't get it working. The only way I get the timer to work is

Comment: I tried however couldn't get it to work. The only way it does work is for me to add `setCountdownTimer(element, year, month, day);` within my `$(document).ready()` within my application.js file but then it break other things like my tabs and audio embedder. I also moved my setCountdownTimer function outside the `$(document).ready()` of my application.js file.

Comment: Try wrapping setCountdownTimer, along with all the vars, inside a $(document).ready() inside of your view instead of application.js sounds like we're on the right track

Comment: I've going back to raw basics in the view to see what's happening. I add a simple alert to see if it works. Wrapping `alert('This is my message');` inside a `$(document).ready()` doesn't fire the alert however the alert works within script tags an no `$(document).ready()`. Strange?

Comment: I managed to get this to work by add the following code to my view. Thanks for you help in providing some insight to help troubleshoot.   `<div id="countDownTimer"></div>
<script>
 var year = <%= @deal.end.year %>;
    var month = <%= @deal.end.month %>;
    var day = <%= @deal.end.day %>;
 var dealEndDate = new Date();
 dealEndDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
 $('#countDownTimer').countdown({until: dealEndDate});
</script>
`