# Countdown timer in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, timer, countdown

In my application, I have a deadline in this format : 2011-08-26 16:45:00 UTC.
In my controller, I am calculating the difference between this date and the current one. The result looks like this : 64:18:13.
I want to create a timer which counts from 64:18:13 until 00:00:00.
How can I do it ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) plugin and also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6025036/49186) if you face any issues